# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21S01]

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, prepared-statement

I am getting this error when trying to post on my custom built social network...:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value
>   list    does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match
>   value count at row 1 in /home//classes/DB.php:10
>
> Stack trace:
>  0 /home//classes/DB.php(10):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>  1 /home//classes/Post.php(13):
>   DB::query('INSERT INTO pos...', Array)
>  2 /home//profile.php(56):
>   Post::createPost('test post again', '1', '1')
>  3 {main}
>  thrown
>   in /home/progreen/thebirding.space/classes/DB.php on line 10

My table structure looks like this:

> CREATE TABLE `posts` (
>    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,
>    `body` varchar(160) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `posted_at` datetime NOT NULL,
>    `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT
>   NULL,
>    `likes` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
>    `postimg`
>   varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>    `topics` varchar(400) DEFAULT
>   NULL,
>    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>    KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
>   CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`
>   (`id`)
>  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

And the function from Post.php looks like this...:

```
public static function createPost($postbody, $loggedInUserId, $profileUserId) {
    if (strlen($postbody) > 220 || strlen($postbody) < 1) {
      die('Incorrect length!');
    }
    if ($loggedInUserId == $profileUserId) {
       DB::query('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (\'\', :postbody, NOW(), :userid, 0, \'\')', array(':postbody'=>$postbody, ':userid'=>$profileUserId));
    } else {
      die('Incorrect user!');
    }
  }
```

This was working perfectly fine and posts was being entered into the database fine until I added the createImgPost function which is this...

```
public static function createImgPost($postbody, $loggedInUserId, $profileUserId) {
    if (strlen($postbody) > 220) {
      die('Incorrect length!');
    }
    if ($loggedInUserId == $profileUserId) {
      DB::query('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (\'\', :postbody, NOW(), :userid, 0, \'\')', array(':postbody'=>$postbody, ':userid'=>$profileUserId));
      $postid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM posts WHERE user_id=:userid ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;', array(':userid'=>$loggedInUserId))[0]['id'];
      return $postid;
    } else {
      die('Incorrect user!');
    }
  }
```

Am I missing something obvious here guys? I'm happy to provide more info and code examples if needed! Many thanks!

Comment: The number of values provided doesn't match the number of columns in the table. One of the reasons you should be explicitly tell the SQL what columns are being inserted into e.g. `INSERT INTO \`table\` (\`column1\`, \`column2\`...) VALUES (...)`.

Comment: Simplify your query string literal by using both double and single quotes rather than escaping single quotes like this `DB::query("INSERT INTO posts VALUES ('', :postbody, NOW(), :userid, 0, '')", array(':postbody'=>$postbody, ':userid'=>$profileUserId));`

Comment: Have tried that @RiggsFolly and stillg etting the same result I'm afraid to say!

Comment: Phillip That was not supposed to be a solution to your issue, just a suggestion to make your code easier to read/maintain

Comment: Ah cheers fella, yep it does make it a lot easier to read anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass postimg value in insert query to match the columns.